# how to add a eraser method to my android draw app

Tags: android, draw, android-custom-view, erase

I have been trying to install a eraser/way to change the drawing color without changing everything that has been previously. Help would be appreciated(please keep in mind i am very new(assume that i dont know anything about android methods)).

```
package com.draw.draw2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainDrawingView extends View
{
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private static Paint paint2 = new Paint();
private static boolean erase;
private Path path = new Path();
private Path path2 = new Path();
Button aButton;

public MainDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);


}
//called when button1 is clicked 
public static void eraser(){
    paint2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path,paint2);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
     paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Get the coordinates of the touch event.
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Set a new starting point
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Connect the points
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);   
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }


    // Makes our view repaint and call onDraw

    invalidate();

    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know somethimg about xFermode?